# Python using regular expression to pick texts

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working with pickups from strings.

A string contains 3 rows, 1st row people’s name (always), 2nd row date and time (fix format), 3rd row a note (could start with numbers and letters). And there are blank rows in between.

What I want are only the names. So I am thinking to use regular expression to locate the date and time, then pick the content before them. However the length of months here (i.e. March, June, February etc) are of different length.

```
sample 1:

Mike Alley

26 February 2005 12:12 AM

50 grams of tobacco



sample 2:

Pichy Lop Annz

22 June 2001 02:06 PM

Lighter and cigar
...
...
...
```

What would be the best way to achieve the goal?

Comment: @hwnd, yes they are.

Comment: @hwnd, thanks for the attention. only 1 name, always the 1st line. My question can also be: how to pick the 1st line of the string?

Comment: @hwnd, you are certainly a sexy king. would you mind put it as an answer to benefit all? thanks.

Comment: What if the first line is blank?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, very good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
>>> s = '''
Mike Alley

26 February 2005 12:12 AM

50 grams of tobacco



sample 2:

Pichy Lop Annz

22 June 2001 02:06 PM

Lighter and cigar
...'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^(\S.*\S)\s*\n\s*\d{1,2}\s+\S+\s+\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+[AP]M', s)
['Mike Alley', 'Pichy Lop Annz']
```

Comment: **Note** each string only contains three rows so there are not two names in  a string.

Comment: yep, it would pick the row which exists before the date line.

Comment: post the reason for downvote. I used the above regex according to this `So I am thinking to use regular expression to locate the date and time, then pick the content before them` statement. Allow op to learn regexes. Note that you can't do all the stuffs using the builtin tools.

Answer (score 3):

If the string is always in this format, you could simply use the following:

```
s.splitlines()[0]
```

If it's possible you may have blank lines before the line containing the name:

```
s.strip().splitlines()[0]
```

Comment: yours' most convenient and straight forward. hope you don't mind I choose below which fits the learning the 're' way.